# Magento1 - How to send a encrypted format of user id in url?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to send encrypted use id to URL. I m getting guest user id through ajax onchange function but on send mail to a user it should be encrypted.

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
 Mage::app();
 umask(0);

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
//$query = "SELECT * FROM toots4trade_guest_user_track WHERE customer_status=0";
$query = "SELECT * FROM toots4trade_guest_user_track WHERE customer_status = 0 ";
$results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

foreach($results as $row){
    $guest_user_id = $row['customer_id'];
     $emailId = $row['customer_email']; 

    $url ="http://stage.tools4trade.co.uk/create_cart.php?guest_user_id=".$guest_user_id;
    mail($emailId,"Abandon Cart",$url);

    $query = "UPDATE toots4trade_guest_user_track SET customer_status = 1 WHERE customer_email ='{$emailId}'";
        $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$guest_user_id = $row['customer_id'];
$guest_user_id = Mage::helper('core')->encrypt($guest_user_id);
$url ="http://stage.tools4trade.co.uk/create_cart.php?guest_user_id=".$guest_user_id;
mail($emailId,"Abandon Cart",$url);
```

**OR**

```
$guest_user_id = $row['customer_id'];
$guest_user_id = base64_encode($guest_user_id);
$url ="http://stage.tools4trade.co.uk/create_cart.php?guest_user_id=".$guest_user_id;
mail($emailId,"Abandon Cart",$url);
```

Comment: are u need url encrypted  or only parameters values?

Comment: Updates ans pls check now

Comment: Updates ans pls check now